# Mover cajas click por click en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cómo realizar **appendChild** caja por caja como en la función 1 donde se utiliza únicamente el **querySelector** mas no el **querySelectorAll** y donde se van moviendo las cajas una por una al hacer click, me interesa hacer esto también en la función 2 donde si se utliza el **querySelectorAll** pero el problema está en que las mueve todas al mismo tiempo y no una por una como en la primera función.

También me gustaría saber la lógica de esto ¿por qué en la primera función no es necesario añadir tanta cosa mientras en la segunda función hay que añadir cosas demás?

```js
// FUNCION 1
function child() {
var but = document.querySelector(".span-box > span");

document.getElementById("span-child").appendChild(but);
}

// FUNCION 2
function child2() {
var butt = document.querySelectorAll(".span-box > span");

for (var i = 0; i < butt.length; i++) {
document.getElementById("span-child").appendChild(butt[i]);
}

}
```

```css
.span-box, #span-child{
background-color: #ccc;
justify-content: center;
display: flex;
}
#span-child{
background-color: beige;
}
.span-box > span, #span-child > span{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 10px;
display: block;
}
.red{
background-color: red;
}
.yellow{
background-color: yellow;
}
.black{
background-color: black;
}
.green{
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="span-box">
<span class="red"></span>
<span class="yellow"></span>
<span class="black"></span>
<span class="green"></span>
</div>


<div id="span-child"></div>

<br/>

<button onclick="child()">Mover cajas funcion 1</button>
<button onclick="child2()">Mover cajas funcion 2</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ese caso no debes usar un bucle: basta con que hagas referencia al primer elemento de la colección:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>test</title>
            <style>
            .span-box, #span-child{
            background-color: #ccc;
            justify-content: center;
            display: flex;
            }
            #span-child{
            background-color: beige;
            }
            .span-box > span, #span-child > span{
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            margin: 10px;
            display: block;
            }
            .red{
            background-color: red;
            }
            .yellow{
            background-color: yellow;
            }
            .black{
            background-color: black;
            }
            .green{
            background-color: green;
            }
            </style>
            <script>
            function child2() {
                var butt = document.querySelectorAll(".span-box > span");
                if(butt.length>0)
                    document.getElementById("span-child").appendChild(butt[0]);
            }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="span-box">
                <span class="red"></span>
                <span class="yellow"></span>
                <span class="black"></span>
                <span class="green"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="span-child"></div>
            <br/>
            <button onclick="child2()">Mover cajas funcion 2</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```